# help someone [do]/[to do]/[in doing]/[on doing] something?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

Given the following sentences:

- They helped us **frame** some experimental evaluations.
- They helped us **to frame** some experimental evaluations.
- They helped us **in framing** some experimental evaluations.
- They helped us **on framing** some experimental evaluations.

Are all them grammatically correct or not? Are there any semantical nuances introduced by each alternative (and why), or do they mean exactly the same? Are there any other alternatives besides these 4 to convey the same meaning? Finally, which alternative is the best one, or does it depend on the context or writing style?

Comment: The first one is the most common. The last one sounds wrong. The second sounds correct, if a bit formal. The third doesn't quite sound right; I suppose it might work, but probably better to use "with" instead of "in".

Answer (score 1):

The first one is normal. The second one sounds a little more formal. I would avoid the last two as they sound a little awkward.

Answer (score 0):

"On framing" would be poor grammar.

The others are fine, save that "To frame" and "in framing" are weaker, which is considered not incorrect, but boring.

Comment: what do you mean by passive? I thought that "to frame" and "in framing" are infinitive and gerund forms, respectively, not passive forms.

Comment: You're right, I'm being incorrectly specific. I will edit.